# What is returned from a GridItem in Google Forms, Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a gridItem in my google form named "Policy Markers". What is returned at the end of a Form Submit trigger. For instance...

```
function onSubmit(e) {
var AnswerObject = e.namedValues();
var PolicyMarkers = AnswerObject['Policy Markers'];
// What is Policy Markers? Is it a single-dimension array?
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried logging its value?  You will be able to see the contents of your object in the Logs upon submission.

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  var AnswerObject = e.namedValues();
  var PolicyMarkers = AnswerObject['Policy Markers'];
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(PolicyMakers, null, 4))
}
```